# Replaced fragment re-appears in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments

The basic architecture of my app is that I show a loading screen in the 3 screens of a `ViewPager` while loading some data(3 fragments for the 3 screens) and when the data has been loaded I show 3 new fragments, **replacing the old fragments** in all the screens of the `ViewPager`.

**root_frameview.xml** (This contains the fragment in each of the screen of the viewpager):-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:id="@+id/root_view">
</FrameLayout>
```

Now, in the adapter class of `ViewPager`, the `Fragment getItem(int position)` method is :-

```
   @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
       Fragment f = new Fragments();
       pageFragments.add(f);//pageFragments is an ArrayList keeping track of all the added fragments
       return f;
    }
```

And the **Fragments** class is

```
public static class Fragments extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.root_frameview, container, false);
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.root_view, new LoadingFragment());//the loading page fragment
        transaction.commit();
        return rootView;
    }

    public void replace() {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.root_view, new LoadedFragment());//the loaded fragment
        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

Note, that it has a `replace()` method which I call when the data has been loaded to replace the fragment(loading page - `LoadingFragment`) with the other fragment - `LoadedFragment`.

### Now comes the problem,

This is the loading screen :-
[image]

And this is the screen which has been loaded :- 
[image]
Seems perfectly fine, huh? But the problem starts here:- When I swipe to **TAB 2** and come back to **TAB 1** , the same loading screen appears as shown in image 1. It does not even loads anything now, just the layout is shown. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3); try this

Comment: @Nithinlal That worked! Thanks. But how? Can you explain. Write it as an anwer and you get a tick :)

Comment: please accept my answer. For a view page the setOffscreenPageLimit is default is 0 so the next page is loaded . when you move to the tab3 ,tab 1 is killed and it will again called the on createview when you swipe to tab1 . This can be solved in change the   setOffscreenPageLimit

Comment: @Nithinlal thanks i got it now. Also please edit your answer and add the explanation that you wrote in the comment so that other users might also get help from your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please set setOffscreenPageLimit for the view pager by simply adding this code

```
 pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
```

For a view page the setOffscreenPageLimit is default is 0 so the next page is loaded . when you move to the tab3 ,tab 1 is killed and it will again called the on createview when you swipe to tab1 . This can be solved in change the setOffscreenPageLimit